# IOS 7 SDK Core Data strange Behavior

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relational-database

I have two entities with many to one relationship Monitoring -< MonitoringStructure. And i see that sometimes it works wrong.

If i want to make MonitoringStructure child of Monitoring normally i did so:

```
MonitoringStructure* monitoring = <Create instance>; 
Monitoring* monitorinStructure = <Create instance>; 
monitorinStructure.monitoring = monitoring;
<Save Context>
```

In SQL logs and after if i restore MonitoringStructure i see that monitorinStructure.monitoring is nil! If i compile my project in IOS6 SDK then it works perfect.

But if do so:

```
MonitoringStructure* monitoring = <Create instance>; 
Monitoring* monitorinStructure = <Create instance>; 
monitorinStructure.monitoring = monitoring;
[monitoring addStructureObject: monitorinStructure];
<Save Context>
```

it works perfect.

What is the reason?

Comment: Do the relationships on both classes have inverse relationships set?

Comment: It seems they may have updated the auto generated code for dealing with NSSets. I know before it use to crash when dealing with sets or orderdered sets.

Comment: Thank you. But it still looks strange